# Can 'Localization native development region' always shows one language?

Tags: ios, iphone

I use CCLocationManager to get the city name, and it get the city's english name, and I want to show its chinese name, so I set 'localization native development region' to 'China' in Target--> info.plist, and in Project-->Localizations, I add chinese language package, and also I delete english language package here, it works well, but if the iOS's language is english, i still get the city's english name, not the chinese name that i want, so how can i get the chinese name no matter the ios's language is? Many thanks.